# Running airodump-ng first. Is it safe?

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, wireless-adapter

So here's my story

So i booted my mac on a live iso image kali linux on usb.

Then plugged in my Netgear WG111v3 and it got auto detected so I used `airmon-ng` to put it into monitor mode playing with my own network in monitor mode for sometime.

Then I put it back into managed mode using `airmon-ng stop` command.

Then I thought what happens if I don't put my Netgear wireless into monitor mode and run `airodump`?

So I tried it out. Well  `airodump` put the wireless adapter into monitor mode itself but it didn't create a new interface like wlan1mon. It just put wlan1 into monitor mode. But `airmon-ng` creates a new interface like wlan1mon.

Then I tried running `airmon-ng stop wlan1` and then threw a output like "Interface not in station mode don't do whatever you did again. Fix this by running some command.

I knew it i messed up so i ran the command it suggested and it replied Assign phy2 to this interface(y/n) I was scared so I replied no and ran `iwconfig` and my interface wlan1 was gone.

So I unplugged and plugged back my wireless adapter and put it into monitor mode the normal way and now it works fine.

My questions

Why did such a  scary message occur?

Did I commit a mistake?

Is my Netgear wireless adapter damaged?

Why does `airmon-ng` change the interface name to wlan1mon when I put it in monitor mode?

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with how the older Wi-Fi stack worked – you couldn't create multiple netdevs for different modes, but had to configure the existing one. (airmon-ng consists of ~1.4k lines of code and 95% of it is just to cope with legacy stuff.)

Comment: I get that error with cards that aren't fully compatible with Kali when I go to put them in monitor mode. The cards that are fully compatible don't need airmon-ng to raw read packets in airodump-ng. But if I take a card that isn't fully compatible, and just try to run airodump-ng from it, it creates multiple instances of a monitor adapter within the same physical interface, and I've seen kernel panics from it. That's why you got a scary warning. As far as I know, it can't damage the card.